# jQuery troubleshooting techniques

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a problem in the code below from a Q&A toggle panel where each `h3` question is followed by a div answer. This particular code is supposed to go through all the questions and answers and close any that are open.

I'm not asking here what's wrong with the code but if there might be some tricks to troubleshooting it I don't know about.  For example, when the `.next()` shifts over to the div for this `h3`, it would be nice to have a variable somewhere that represented that div jQuery object, i.e, the result of the `next()`. And in the `slideToggle(1000)` it would be nice to see the the toggle state variable that `slideToggle()` is looking at.

```
$('#qa h3').each(function() {
debugger;
this$ = $(this);
if(this$.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    this$.toggleClass("ui-state-active ui-state-default")
   .next()
    .toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active")
    .slideToggle(1000);
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You're going to have to break up the queue'd methods but you should be able to `console.log(this)` at any time in your script to see the obejct(s) that you're affecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply print the variables you're requesting to the console using `console.log`.

```
$('#qa h3').each(function() {
  debugger;

  $this = $(this);
  console.log($this);

  if($this.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    console.log('$this has class .ui-state-active');
    console.log('$this.next() = ' + $this.next());

    $this.toggleClass("ui-state-active ui-state-default").next().toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active").slideToggle(1000);
  }
}
```

Just for the books, I think your issue is that you're missing a curly brace. I've added the missing brace to the above code.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, that last brace isn't missing in the real code.  I just goofed by not including it in the code I posted here. And those kinds of errors, but the way, are easy to spot because 1) the code doesn't parse, and 2) the Firebug console automatically displays a red Syntax Error.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought I'd mention it because simple syntax errors are often the culprits. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (this$.hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    // code added for troubleshooting purposes
    var that = this$.next();
    console.log(that);
    // end
    this$.toggleClass("ui-state-active ui-state-default")
    .next()
    .toggleClass("ui-accordion-content-active")
    .slideToggle(1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes, lots of console.logs is about the best we can do, I guess.  What we need is a .console() method that you could put in the queue, where its "this" was the first item in the current wrapped set.